# "If I didn't have" vs. "if I hadn't had"

Tags: tenses, conditionals

Can someone please tell me if these sentences are correct? I prefer number one. Here I am trying to talk about a past condition that didn't actually happen because the person *had* the example sentences and they *did* understand.

> 1. If I didn't have the example sentences, I wouldn't have understood the text.
> 2. If I hadn't had the example sentences, I wouldn't have understood the text.

Comment: Why do you prefer #1? Familiarity? This is what many (maybe even **most**) native English speakers would write and say, it's true, but that's only because they don't know traditional (but now _high-level_) English grammar well enough to know how to use the past subjunctive (hypothetical/unreal condition).

Answer (score 10):

If you are talking about an event or state that didn’t happen, the *if* clause needs the past perfect construction, and the main clause needs to consist of *would have* + past participle. This is sometimes known to foreign learners of English as the Third Conditional.  Such a sentence imagines something that might have happened, but didn’t, and it is now too late to do anything about it.

What this means for your examples is that the second would be the normal way of putting it. The *if* clause consists of the past perfect *hadn’t had* and the main clause consists of *wouldn’t have* followed by the past participle *understood*. If you find this difficult to follow, it may become a little clearer if you make the sentence positive: *If I had had the example sentences, I would have understood the text.*

Comment: +1. You could have added something like *If I did not have the example sentences, I would not understand the text* or more positively *If I had the example sentences, I would understand the text*.

Comment: @Henry: Those two sentences are present subjunctives, not past subjunctives; therefore, they aren't germane to an answer for a question about a past hypothetical.

Comment: @Bill Franke: I see no subjunctives.

Comment: Unreal hypothetical conditions in the past use past perfect (pluperfect), e.g., "**If I hadn't had a cold, I wouldn't have sneezed during my coronation**" vs. "**If I hadn't been sick, I wouldn't have sneezed during my coronation**". Both are past subjunctives that are parallel to the OP's question. If they're not subjunctives, then what term would you use to label them? "Third conditional" is just another way of saying "a structure used for talking about unreal situations in the past".

Comment: ["A pluperfect subjunctive may be considered to exist; its form (had with past participle) does not differ from the corresponding indicative, but a distinction can be sought in the possibility of inversion: had I sung... (equivalent to if I had sung)."](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_subjunctive#Use_of_the_past_subjunctive) => "**Had I not had the example sentences, I wouldn't have understood the text**". I think we're at odds only about terminology.

Comment: I would call them conditional sentences in which the _if_ clause consists of the past perfect construction, and the main clause consists of _would(n’t)_ followed by the past participle. I know of no professional linguist who would describe any of the verbs used as subjunctive. Subjunctive, as Huddleston and Pullum say, is not ‘a term for an inflectional category, but for a syntactic construction employing the plain form of the verb.’

Comment: Well, you know what I think of Huddleston and Pullum's _CGEL_ analysis of English grammar: **highly politicized & unreliable**. All subjunctives with an "**if**" clause are conditionals: unreal or hypothetical conditionals. As I said, we disagree about terms, not about substance. I'm perfectly happy to call it a Third Conditional, but that's lipstick: "Harijan" for "Untouchable", "Dalit" for "Harijan", "[Pacification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Politics_and_the_English_Language)" for destruction and murder.

Comment: @Bill Franke: It isn't just H&P. Here’s Bas Aarts, Professor of Linguistics, University College, London: ‘The labels “subjunctive” and “imperative” . . . do not apply to inflections . .  . but to clausal constructions.’ And David Crystal: ‘The subjunctive is used very little in modern English, being mainly restricted to formal or formulaic expression.’ And here’s me: http://realgrammar.posterous.com/subjunctive

Comment: @BarrieEngland: Okay. You've convinced me to stop using the term **subjunctive** and to stick with **unreal conditions**. Thank you for the citations.

Comment: @Bill: My examples start in the same way as your first example.

Comment: Could you document the Aarts quote? He seems to be a man after my own heart, or at least one mounted for this matter on my hobbyhorse.

Comment: @StoneyB http://www.amazon.com/Oxford-Modern-English-Grammar-Aarts/dp/0199533199/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1352206904&sr=1-1&keywords=oxford+modern+english+grammar

Answer (score 2):

*If I didn't have the example sentences...*, using the present 'have', must refer to the present, and so would have to go on ...*I wouldn't understand the text.*  If referring to the past, you must use the past form *had*, as in example 2.

Comment: Points in imaginary time can be imagined as present or past, so the past reference is lost.  "If I were not here (yesterday evening), you would have left" is as good as "If I were not here (right now), you would leave".

Answer (score 1):

Strictly speaking, the second is the normal construction. This is a form of the conditional that didn't happen. Here is an explanation:

> If I hadn't had the example sentences, I wouldn't have understood the text. *You had the examples that's why you got the text.*

The second part of the conditional could also come to the present:

> If I hadn't gotten the keys, I wouldn't be able to go to my apartment now.*You are probably on the way to your apartment.*

That said, in some parts of the United States, the first form also seems to be common in spoken English. So don't be surprised if you hear something similar.

Comment: What does "**If I hadn't got the keys**" mean? "**If I hadn't picked up the keys and put them in my pocket**" or "**If I didn't have the keys**"? AmE is "**If I hadn't gotten the keys**", or has that too changed in the 30 years since I left? And the first form is ultracommon in writing as well in a world where people write as they speak rather than to communicate clearly. The second sentence, I contend, is abnormal because so few native speakers know how to use it, so they tend more and more to use the first or to mumble incoherently.

Comment: @BillFranke: Sorry, that was a typo -:) But *got* seems to be commonly used too in the same context. Not sure why.

Comment: [Sigh of relief]. Thank you for the info. I don't watch American TV anymore and rarely have time for movies, so I'm not up on all the latest linguistic developments that don't appear in the newspapers and blogs that I read online.

Comment: *Have got*, as in "I've got", meaning simply 'have' was in my youth pretty generally distinguished from *have gotten*, the perfect construction. But in modal contexts, *gotten* seems to be collapsing into *got* - which may be regretted (if not downright deplored), but is probably inevitable.

Answer (score 0):

When the form which sounds right (1) is shown to be grammatically incorrect, avoid the issue by reconstructing the sentence.

> Without the example sentences, I wouldn't have understood the text.

Comment: Recasting one's grammatically incorrect or syntactically clunky sentences is only one reasonable possibility, but it perpetuates ignorance unless coupled with an admonition to learn the correct grammar and how to craft better sentences.

Comment: Since subjunctive grammar is dying anyway, and I, for one, don't really want to keep it alive on a respirator, evasion may be the best solution, here.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is the same as that between "If I was not given the samples" vs "If I were not given the samples".  The latter is more correct, but it sounds out-of-date.  Traditionally, this is a condition contrary to fact, and requires the subjunctive.

The subjunctive in English generally looks 'past-like' when it is present.  "Were I not here, you would leave" is a statement about what would be going on NOW, but it looks past.  Similarly this form looks past-perfect when it is simply past.  So the "hadn't had" construction is the right version here.

OTOH, everyone universally despises having a whole set of conjugation rules that are so seldom used.  So the subjunctive is totally optional except in the most formal of writing.